# JS: build object based on given object parent's property?

Tags: javascript, quasar

I am trying to create a JS object that hold all the urls.

I am trying to achieve this so I have a data() part:

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'MyPage',
  data() {
    backendUrls: {...}
  }
})
```

In a more simple way it would look like this:

```
backendUrls: {
  baseUrl: "http://localhost:8080",
  baseUrlWithPrefix: function() { return this.baseUrl + "/ver1"; }
  userAdd: function() { return this.baseUrlWithPrefix() + "/user/add"; }
}
```

I could use the `this` keyword since it pointed to the same object where the given property also exists.

But I would like to split a bit more and create objects in the object:

```
backendUrls: {
  baseUrl: "http://localhost:8080",
  generalUrls: {
    baseUrlWithPrefix: ...
  },
  socketUrls: {
    messageUrls: {
      userAdd: ...
    }
  }
}
```

Here if I try `generalUrls: { baseUrlWithPrefix: function() { return this.baseUrl + "/ver1"; }}`, it won't work because it does not find the `baseUrl` since the `this` keyword points on the `generalUrls` object and not the `backendUrls` object where the `baseUrl` exists.

I'd need something like this:

```
backendUrls: {
  baseUrl: "http://localhost:8080",
  generalUrls: {
    baseUrlWithPrefix: function() { return {goBackToParentObject}.this.baseUrl + "/ver1"; }
  },
  socketUrls: {
    messageUrls: {
      userAdd: function() { return {goBackToParentObject}.this.generalUrls.baseUrlWithPrefix() + "/user/add"; }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the way you call the function like this

```js
const backendUrls = {
  baseUrl: "http://localhost:8080",
  generalUrls: {
    baseUrlWithPrefix: function() { return this.baseUrl + "/ver1"; }
  },
}

const example = backendUrls.generalUrls.baseUrlWithPrefix.bind(backendUrls);

example();
```